# XQuery Generate Concatenate But Adding Extra Whitespace Character

Tags: string, xquery

I have a problem generating group of strings using XQuery. Every concatenate is adding extra one white space after another.

For example, my XML file like this

```
<createRequest>
    <transactionType>GAME1</transactionType>
    <listOfBoard>
        <board>
            <gameType>RegularA</gameType>
            <listOfBoardData>
                <boardData>6</boardData>
                <boardData>12</boardData>
            </listOfBoardData>
        </board>
        <board>
            <gameType>RegularB</gameType>
            <listOfBoardData>
                <boardData>7</boardData>
                <boardData>8</boardData>
                <boardData>11</boardData>
                <boardData>21</boardData>
                <boardData>28</boardData>
                <boardData>47</boardData>
            </listOfBoardData>
        </board>
    </listOfBoard>
    <ticketPrice>600</ticketPrice>
</createRequest>
```

My code

```
let $requestMessage := //createRequest

let $boardData := 
for $eachOfListBoardData in 1 to count($requestMessage/listOfBoard/board/listOfBoardData)
return
   fn:concat(fn:string-join($requestMessage/listOfBoard/board[$eachOfListBoardData]/listOfBoardData/boardData, ","),":")


return $boardData
```

but the result is outputing extra whitespace after each of group, as shown below

```
6,12: 7,8,11,21,28,47: 4,11,21,26,28,31: 7,28,31,45,46,49: 15,29,34,36,41,42: 5,7,14,21,42,46:
```

and it is adding ':' after the number '46'

My desired output is   `6,12:7,8,11,21,28,47:4,11,21,26,28,31:7,28,31,45,46,49:15,29,34,36,41,42:5,7,14,21,42,46`

any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "...but the result is outputing extra whitespace after each of group..."

`string-join()` passing empty string as the 2nd parameter would help you fix that.

> "and it is adding ':' after the number '46'"

You can use `if-else` construct to append `:` only if current item is not the last item, see the complete XQuery example below :

```
let $requestMessage := //createRequest
let $lastBoard := ($requestMessage/listOfBoard/board/listOfBoardData)[last()]

let $boards := 
for $board in $requestMessage/listOfBoard/board/listOfBoardData
return
    if($board is $lastBoard)
        then fn:string-join($board/boardData, ",")
    else fn:concat(fn:string-join($board/boardData, ","),":")

let $boardData := fn:string-join($boards, "")

return $boardData
```